# How to Convert IntPtr to native c++ object

Tags: c#, .net, interop, c++-cli

I have COM dll that I am using in C++/Cli, one of the method in this COM dll returns IntPtr
I want to convert that back to the native object pointer. How I can do that ? please in put

Comment: You need to provide the declarations for the COM method and the "native object".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IntPtr is an integral type, you need to first convert it to a pointer type:

```
  IntPtr somePtr;
  ...
  Mumble* fooPtr = (Mumble*)(void*)somePtr;
```

Or the more readable version:

```
  Mumble* fooPtr = (Mumble*)somePtr.ToPointer();
```

The method call will be optimized away at runtime.

Answer (score 8):

`IntPtr` has a `ToPointer` method that returns a `void*`. Call this method, then use `reintepret_cast` to cast this pointer to the right native type.

Comment: I think it should be fine to use a `static_cast` in this case. I know of no good reason to `reintepret_cast` a void-pointer to another pointer type.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to modify [Hans Passant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4277729/1581050),
`IntPtr` directly returns void pointer .. which you can cast easily in any type of native C++ Pointer.

```
IntPtr somePtr;
Mumble* fooPtr = (Mumble*)somePtr.ToPointer();
```

here `.ToPointer()` will return void pointer, now you can cast to your custom pointer type.